# HIVE SQL ISO timestamp. how to convert from string to numeric continuous?

Tags: sql, hive

So I have a timestamp column that is formatted as a string and looks like this:

**2021-06-07T05:00:52.000000Z**

Any advice on how I can get this converted to a normal numeric continuous timestamp?

How to deal with the "T" and the "Z"?

Comment: "timestamp column that is formatted as a string"?!?

Comment: after converting to normal timestamp string you can apply unix_timestamp() to get seconds part as bigint